# Would a Death note still work, if a heart attack could lead to someone else's death?

Tags: death-note

L has just thought of a cunning plan to prevent himself being killed by a Death note:

> He straps a device to his heart that directly links to an equivalent device strapped to Watari's (his butler) heart. If either heart stops beating (or the device is removed), then the other self-detonates and kills the other person. Which thus renders the Death note essentially useless against either of them, given the following rule:

**Even though only one name is written in the Death Note, if it influences and causes other humans that are not written in it to die, the victim’s cause of death will be a heart attack** ~ *Rule XXVI - II* linked [death note rules wiki](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note)

Is this possible, or would L just die from a heart attack anyway?

Comment: This is not a duplicate because this question aims towards a death that indirectly causes another one. The linked "original" question asks for people who only can lieve or die together. BTW the anser is in rule 1. When a person's name is written in the death note, (s)he will die. This death will influence other people's lifes and deaths and killing someone with the DN lenghtens the lives of some and shortens the lives of others. The only gain would be to make sure that L dies on a heart attack to indentify Kira as the murderer.